# Using BASH sed command to strip a line

Tags: bash, sed

I have one line in a html file which i located using

```
 grep -m 1 'argument'
```

That line looks a lot like this

```
<tag option="something" option="something"><span option="something">&nbsp;Text1 </span> - <span option="something"> Text2&nbsp;</span></tag>
```

I need to extract Text 1 and Text 2 using seperate lines, what do I do? I get that I need to use sed, I have removed tag and span at the begginng leaving me with

```
   Text1 </span> - <span...........</tag>
```

but I need only Text1 and i realy dont know how to remove that non-static Text2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the lines are exactly always looking like the example you provide, you can do it with a regexp.

But in all other cases, you should really use a XML parser instead (for example, use perl : twig, or others)

So here is a regexp, but you've been warned ^^

```
#replace each <...> with "|", so you can easily separate each fields
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>/|/g'
```

You can then fetch each section by using that new "simple" separator, `|`:

```
grep 'argument' | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>/|/g' | awk -F'|' '{print $3}'  #shows Text1. Change $3 to $5 to fetch the Text2
```

Comment: works perfectly, now i need to re-read this to understand what exactly was done :D anyway thank you!

Comment: One thing = it leaves &nbsp; I would like to remove those too

Comment: the sed command is of the form `s/A/B/g` : `s`(earch and replace), look for `A`, replace with `B`, and `g` is for "globally", ie not only the 1st occurence per line, but globally across all occurence on the line. Then `<[^>]*>` is a regexp matching a `<` followed by `[^>]` ("anything except a >), `*` is the preceding thing "0, 1 or more times". So it will match any `<....>` [where `....` does NOT contain `>`, otherwise it would match almost the whole line, as regexp are trying to cover as much as possible]. So it will replace each `<...>` with `|`

Comment: to remove any &nbsp; :   add a command to get rid of it: `grep 'argument' | sed -e 's/ *\&nbsp; *//g' -e 's/<[^>]*>/|/g' | awk -F'|' '{print $3}'`   : this will also get rid of any `&nbsp;` on the line [and any spaces before/after it]

Comment: thanks for the comment. Realy appriciate and i got rid of the &nbsp; with sed `'s/\&nbsp;//g'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is much shorter way to do that using grep and perl regular expressions.

```
$ cat testfile # I've placed your line in this file
<tag option="something" option="something"><span option="something">&nbsp;Text1 </span> - <span option="something"> Text2&nbsp;</span></tag>
```

---

```
$ grep -Po '<span[^>]*>\K[^<]*' testfile
&nbsp;Text1 
 Text2&nbsp;
```

But if you want to get exactly `Text1` and `Text2` you need a bit more complicated regexp. And here it is:

```
$ grep -Po '<span[^>]*>(&nbsp;)?\s*\K.*?(?=\s*(&nbsp;)?</span>)' testfile
Text1
Text2
```

### Some explanation:

This regex is using `lookaround` syntax or `zero-width assertions`. [You can read about it here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

`\K` might be unfamiliar too. It is very similar to zero-width assertions and is greatly explained [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns). Here is a quote from that link:

> There is a special form of this construct, called \K , which causes the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the \K and not include it in $& . This effectively provides variable-length look-behind. The use of \K inside of another look-around assertion is allowed, but the behaviour is currently not well defined.

### Ok, but why?

One of the greatest things in this approach is that you're already using grep, you can possibly combine this regex with your search pattern so you will only need one `grep` command, unlike [Oliver`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20799574/2698019) which uses `grep`, `sed` and `awk`.
**But** still, there are special tools to parse xml, please use them instead of this regex porn.